# Point MapWinGIS to a URL instead of a Tile provider

Tags: google-maps, mapwingis

Since Google no longer allows direct access to their tiles, how to get Maps to show up in the ocx window. I have an Google API account, but it's not needed for Google Maps.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Has searching not revealed anything?

Comment: Searched Google api docs and examples, also MapWinGIS doc pages with no success. Closest I have found is adding a webBrowser control to the form which does work with Google but that's not what I need. I want the funtionality of the mapWinGIS OCX window.

Comment: What is the url you want to use? Is it a WMS? If so you can add it as a WMS layer. If it is not a WMS it is probably needed to implement the url directly in MapWinGIS. This needs resources.

Comment: This is the url to the Google Maps embed api --- https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view?zoom=9&center=29.7604,-95.3698&key=.my_secret_key.  Works fine in a browser window with my key loaded.  I would like to add this map as base layer then put various calculated attributes in layers on top of it.